# error: ‘pthread_mutex_t’ has no member named ‘wait’

Tags: c, multithreading

Getting error  error: ‘pthread_mutex_t’ has no member named ‘wait’ for this code not able to understand why? I have already declared on top pthread_mutex_t mutex; still getting the same error.

Im trying to implement two phase barrier as given in Little book of Semaphore book.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>


int thread_count;

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void* MyThread(void* rank);
   void* Hello(void* rank)

    {

        long my_rank = (long) rank;

        int a = 0,i;

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)

        {

              int n = 5;
              int count = 0;

              mutex = Semaphore(1)

              barrier = Semaphore(0)

                  a = a + 0.9*MAX_INT;

                  printf("this is %d iteration\n",i);

              mutex.wait()

              count = count + 1;

              mutex.signal()

              if count == n: barrier.signal() //unblock ONE thread

              barrier.wait()

              barrier.signal()

       }

    }
```

Comment: You appear to be missing several semicolons.  int count =0 for one. This looks more like c++ code as you cannot access functions in C like mutex.wait() as mutex is not an instance to a class

Comment: how can I access in C?

Answer (score 0):

`pthreads` are a C API, and are not object-oriented.  As such, the library does not export objects with methods, but functions that take pointers to things as arguments.

You create a `pthread_mutex_t` by calling:

```
int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr);
```

Or initializing it to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

You acquire a mutex by calling:

```
int pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

and release it by calling:

```
int pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

In your example, I don't know what `Semaphore` or `barrier` refer to.

Actually, that `if` statement is positively Pythonic.  Are you trying to shove some partially transformed Python code down the C compiler's throat?

Comment: im working on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522174/two-phase-barrier-implementation-using-posix-semaphores

Comment: is it possible you to help me in this question?